# jquery catch delayed each is finished?

Tags: jquery, delay, each

```
$("#div_game_container").on("click", ".square", squareClick);

function squareClick() {
    var group = $(this).data("group");

    if ($("." + group).hasClass("active")) {

        // off click event
        $("#div_game_container").off("click", ".square", squareClick);

        $("." + group).each(function (index) {
            $(this).delay(100 * index).fadeOut(100);
        });

        // on click event. this line does not wait "each" function 
        $("#div_game_container").on("click", ".square", squareClick);
}
```

above code does not work. Actually, it works but not my expected. I commented out what is the problem.

Also I add the delay like this:

```
$("#div_game_container").delay(each_delay_time).on("click", ".square", squareClick);
```

but there is no change. How can I catch that "each" iteration is finished? I want to prevent click event, while each method is running, and after each method finished, then active click event

Comment: Are you saying you want to make sure that you've run through the entire group before executing the re-bind?

Comment: There are square sets/groups, when I click the square of a group, I fade out them. In this time, user does not click other squres. Each group must not fade out same time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) object:

```
$("." + group).each(function (index) {
    $(this).delay(100 * index).fadeOut(100);
});
$("." + group).promise().done(function() {
    $("#div_game_container").on("click", ".square", squareClick);
});
```

Comment: Bang on. Could event attach it to the `each` so there is only one `$("." + group)`.

Comment: @gillesc Sure could! I segregated it (in this instance) for legibility.

Comment: @DevlshOne, if I have another "each" function in promise().done() how can I catch this second "each" method if it is done? I add nested promise().done() but does not work. Please help me...