# javascript dom object array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

there are objects in my document. I create an array from these objects in "each" method and I try to get them in another "each" method. I write array in console for two "each" method. Elements are match but their positions are not.

```
var deletedObjects = [];

$(".active").each(function (index) {
    var deletedObject = $(this);

    console.log(deletedObject.position());
    console.log("-------------------------------------");

    deletedObjects.push(deletedObject);
    deletedObject.delay(100 * index).fadeOut(100);

}).promise().done(function () {
    console.log("Same list again");
    console.log("-------------------------------------");
    $.each(deletedObjects,function(){
        console.log($(this).position());
        console.log("-------------------------------------");
    });
});
```

**console.log output**

```
Object {top: 80, left: 160} 
------------------------------------- 
Object {top: 80, left: 200} 
------------------------------------- 
Object {top: 80, left: 240} 
------------------------------------- 
Same list again
------------------------------------- 
Object {top: 0, left: 0} 
------------------------------------- 
Object {top: 0, left: 0}
------------------------------------- 
Object {top: 0, left: 0} 
-------------------------------------
```

is this code `deletedObject.delay(100 * index).fadeOut(100);` running before second each? Why element positions change? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The element position is changed because it is no longer displayed... yes the animations(`fadeOut`) is executed before the second each... because you have attached that code as a done callback to the animation queue promise

Comment: @ArunPJohny, thanks. But how can I fix it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bsa2jL88/1/ - why are you using `promise().done()`?

Comment: Can you try with another attr like id? I'm guessing maybe the fade out changes the position of the div

Comment: because, there is an event and I stop it before first "each" method, and in promise().done() I bind its event again. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708839/jquery-catch-delayed-each-is-finished

Comment: @ArunPJohny a jQuery object isn't a promise until you call `.promise`.  What confuses people sometimes is that `$.when` automatically converts every parameter into a promise if they aren't one already.

Comment: All their attrs are same. Only changed positions...

Comment: @Alnitak I think calling promise() returns a promise object.. not calling done().... isn't it - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bsa2jL88/2/

Comment: sorry, yes, that's what I meant - you have to call `.promise()` to get the object that has the `.done()` method.

Comment: Should I insert the positions to another array? I dont find any another elegant way...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the second part runs on `.promise().done` and the animation is a promise, so it will only execute once all the elements in the first part is faded out. I tested by moving the second part out, and it does print it with the original element positions:

```
var deletedObjects = [];

$(".active").each(function (index) {
    var deletedObject = $(this);

    console.log(deletedObject.position());
    console.log("-------------------------------------");

    deletedObjects.push(deletedObject);
    deletedObject.delay(100 * index).fadeOut(100);

});

console.log("Same list again");
console.log("-------------------------------------");
$.each(deletedObjects, function () {
    console.log($(this).position());
    console.log("-------------------------------------");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions. The first you found yourself: Push the position objects into a second array and refer to that.

The second works as follows:
The fadeOut() ends up with setting the objects style `display: 'none'`. As @Arun P Johny explained, a non-displayed element hasn't a position any more. So we switch for a short unperceptable moment the display property to its default value, take the elements position and afterwards set display back to none.

I show only the snippet with your promise.done-callback:

```
}).promise().done(function () {
    console.log("Same list again");
    console.log("-------------------------------------");
    $(deletedObjects).css('display', '')
        .each(function(){
            console.log($(this).position());
            console.log("-------------------------------------");
        })
        .css('display', 'none');
});
```

Since this method is expensive and a bit circuitously I would prefer a second array.